# List of all interesting stars to visit

Tags: star-control-2

Part of StarControl II's (known these days as [The Ur-Quan Masters](http://sc2.sourceforge.net/)) magic is exploring the universe. You do this for two main purposes:

- Resources - with which you evolve your ship and abilities
- Quest\Plot related encounters, objects, homeworlds etc

At some point you grind enough to exhaust the first point and remain free to pursue the latter. When I was 16, maybe I didn't mind grinding all the worlds in the map, but these days, I simply want to enjoy the quests and plot.

**Did someone compile a list of all star systems with anything more than minerals\life forms to harvest?**

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Yes, [there is a list of places of interest on the SC2 wiki](http://wiki.uqm.stack.nl/List_of_places_of_interest)

Answer (score 2):

GameFAQs has several SC2 FAQs here: http://www.gamefaqs.com/3do/584500-star-control-ii/faqs

Among them:

- [SC2 Star System FAQ/location list](http://www.gamefaqs.com/3do/584500-star-control-ii/faqs/31697) - has a complete list of stars with marks on which ones are interesting
- [A largs SC2 FAQ](http://www.gamefaqs.com/3do/584500-star-control-ii/faqs/47293), which has lists of Rainbow worlds; species homeworlds; and Ruby/Sapphire/Emerald Worlds (these are extremely high value as they are full of 25-price resources)

Answer (score 0):

The "[Star Control II Role Playing Resource Guide](http://cd.textfiles.com/pcgamesexe/pcge199807/STARCON2/MANUAL/RESOURCE.PDF)" will answer most everything you would ever want to know.